# Load balancing setup in WSO2 with AWS ELB

Tags: wso2, amazon-elb

I am trying to do Load balancing in WSO2. I have setup three instances of AWS and every instances have WSO2 Identity server, WSO2 Application manager and WSO2 Custom services(Rest Web services).

```
I want to implement Load balancing feature. To achieve this, I have setup AWS ELB with three instances in AWS management console. I have also setup clustering feature in every instance where I have put Instance-I as Manager node and Instance-II and instance-III as worker node.  I am following this URL "https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+a+Cluster"
```

But still I am facing problem. After calling 1000 concurrent requests from JMeter, server got down and saying "Connection closed by target host before receiving the response".

Can anyone suggest me the exact procedure to achieve this.

Thanks
Anup Kumar Shrivastaw